# CSS sidebar with scrollbar with absolute tooltips

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position

I'm really struggling with this one to wrap my head around, I have a sidebar that in one of the list items is a `div` which is named `tooltip`. What I'm trying to figure out is how to make the sidebar scroll up and down without trimming the tooltip?

Here is a [jsFiddle without Scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/STDHQ/) [jsFiddle with Scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/STDHQ/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Blank"/>
            <div class="tooltip">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Blank"/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul, li{
    list-style:none;
}
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
ul{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
}
li{
    padding:10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    top: 0;
    right:-40px;
}
```

Comment: How is the sidebar scrolling?  How is the tooltip getting trimmed?  It is not quite clear what is happening that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

remove `position: relative` from `li`

and add to the container you want it positioned relatively to ..

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/STDHQ/3/